# Как поменять цвет для такой SVG при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Код SVG:

```
<svg width="261" height="63" viewBox="0 0 261 63" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0_2_453)">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6.03942 -0.000488281H29.3412C27.3784 4.17237 28.083 9.10856 30.3478 12.9761C36.3871 23.6118 42.4768 34.2475 48.5664 44.8832C45.8487 49.5649 43.2317 54.2467 40.5643 58.9284C39.4068 60.9131 37.595 62.8977 35.1289 62.9486C32.6628 62.9995 30.7 61.1166 29.5425 59.0302C20.1815 42.7459 10.8709 26.3598 1.50992 10.0246C0.352378 7.98901 -0.553522 5.49547 0.453034 3.20549C1.40926 1.01728 3.87532 0.152177 6.03942 -0.000488281Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.66"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M38.35 -0.000488281H96.2773C98.3407 0.203066 100.656 0.864617 101.713 2.79838C102.87 4.98659 102.216 7.63279 101.058 9.66833C92.2007 25.1384 83.3933 40.6086 74.5357 56.1296C73.5291 57.8089 72.6735 59.6409 71.365 61.1166C70.0062 62.5924 67.8421 63.4575 65.8793 62.7451C64.0675 62.1344 62.7589 60.6077 61.8531 58.9793C52.4921 42.4914 43.0808 26.0544 33.6695 9.61744C32.5623 7.63279 31.8577 5.03748 33.0152 2.90016C34.0721 0.966394 36.2865 0.203066 38.35 -0.000488281Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.66"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M204.533 58.3691L205.388 58.42C205.791 59.4887 206.646 60.71 207.703 61.1171C210.371 62.1858 213.39 62.1349 216.108 61.3716C217.064 61.0662 218.121 60.5065 218.574 59.5905C218.826 59.1325 218.977 58.7254 219.027 58.2165C219.128 56.8934 218.121 55.7229 216.813 55.5194C213.34 54.9596 209.716 55.8756 206.344 54.8578C204.935 54.4507 204.382 52.7205 204.684 51.3974C204.935 49.9725 206.143 49.0056 207.401 48.4968C208.962 47.8861 210.673 47.7334 212.384 47.7843C213.944 47.8352 215.202 47.937 216.561 48.7512C217.668 49.4128 218.675 50.2779 219.128 51.601L218.272 51.8045C217.92 51.2956 217.165 50.4305 216.309 49.769C215.253 48.9548 214.548 48.8021 213.34 48.6494C211.075 48.2932 208.609 48.6494 206.697 49.8708C205.086 50.8376 204.885 53.8401 206.948 54.3998C210.522 55.3158 214.296 54.0436 217.819 55.214C218.876 55.5194 219.53 56.4863 219.782 57.504C220.084 58.878 219.53 60.1502 218.474 61.0662C216.259 62.9491 212.736 62.8982 209.867 62.542C207.452 62.1858 204.935 60.8627 204.533 58.3691ZM244.09 42.8481C244.292 42.8481 244.644 42.8481 244.845 42.8481C244.845 47.8861 244.845 53.8401 244.896 59.1834C244.896 60.4556 244.896 61.4733 245.097 62.7456L244.443 62.7964C243.939 61.4224 244.09 59.9467 244.09 58.5218C244.09 53.2803 244.04 48.0897 244.09 42.8481ZM251.237 42.8481C251.388 42.8481 251.69 42.8481 251.841 42.8481V47.9879L259.39 48.0388L259.34 48.6494H251.841C251.941 51.9572 251.64 55.3158 252.042 58.6236C252.193 59.9467 253.149 61.0153 254.408 61.3716C256.37 61.9822 258.484 61.6769 260.497 61.8296L260.598 62.2876C260.145 62.4402 258.987 62.3384 258.534 62.3893C256.572 62.3384 254.408 62.542 252.747 61.3207C251.489 60.3029 251.237 58.5727 251.187 57.046C251.187 54.2472 251.187 51.4483 251.187 48.5985C250.281 48.5985 249.375 48.5985 248.469 48.5985C248.469 48.4459 248.419 48.1405 248.419 47.9879C249.324 47.9879 250.281 47.9879 251.187 47.9879C251.237 46.2577 251.237 44.5783 251.237 42.8481ZM152.796 48.4968C151.89 48.4968 150.581 48.4459 148.92 49.6672C147.763 50.5323 147.159 52.059 147.058 53.4838C146.756 56.1809 146.907 59.8958 149.826 61.168C152.594 62.2367 155.815 62.1858 158.583 61.168C160.093 60.6082 160.697 59.0816 161.301 57.7076C161.452 57.6567 161.754 57.504 161.905 57.4531C161.704 59.6922 160.144 61.7787 157.879 62.1858C154.909 62.7964 151.638 62.9491 148.87 61.5242C145.951 59.6413 146.152 55.5703 146.555 52.4661C146.756 50.5832 148.115 49.1583 149.675 48.2932C150.33 47.937 150.783 47.8352 151.487 47.7843C153.249 47.6825 155.01 47.6825 156.772 47.7843C157.879 47.7843 158.382 48.1405 158.483 48.1914C160.244 49.0056 161.653 50.5832 161.905 52.5678C161.1 52.4152 160.898 51.4992 160.546 50.8885C160.244 50.227 159.741 49.7181 159.137 49.4128C158.382 48.9548 157.678 48.5985 156.822 48.4968C155.513 48.2932 154.004 48.5477 152.796 48.4968ZM170.612 48.4968C168.548 48.7003 166.737 50.2779 166.384 52.3643C165.881 55.1123 165.78 58.4709 167.844 60.6082C170.008 62.2367 172.927 61.9822 175.443 61.8296C177.456 61.7278 179.469 60.4556 179.922 58.42C180.577 55.7738 180.627 52.6696 179.167 50.2779C177.104 47.8352 173.48 48.2932 170.612 48.4968ZM169.203 48.1405C171.971 47.479 174.94 47.4281 177.658 48.2932C180.325 49.2092 181.08 52.4152 181.03 54.9596C181.08 57.5549 180.526 60.8627 177.809 61.9313C175.091 62.8982 172.071 62.7964 169.303 62.1858C166.334 61.5242 165.327 58.1656 165.378 55.4685C165.277 52.6696 166.082 49.0056 169.203 48.1405ZM189.887 48.8021C189.887 48.7512 189.887 48.7003 189.837 48.6494C188.327 48.9548 186.918 50.4305 186.717 51.9063C186.163 55.4176 186.616 59.0307 186.415 62.5929C185.559 62.2876 185.911 61.2698 185.811 60.6082C185.962 57.5549 185.509 54.4507 186.113 51.4483C186.314 49.8708 187.623 48.853 188.931 48.0897L190.139 47.8861C192.001 47.6825 193.863 47.6825 195.675 47.8352C195.776 47.8352 196.48 48.0388 196.833 48.0897L196.883 48.0388L196.984 48.0897C198.493 48.9548 199.701 50.3796 199.802 52.1607C200.054 55.5194 199.852 58.9289 199.903 62.3384C199.752 62.3384 199.45 62.3384 199.299 62.3384C199.198 58.9798 199.5 55.672 199.097 52.3134C198.946 50.7867 198.04 49.311 196.581 48.9039C196.43 48.853 196.279 48.853 196.078 48.8021C195.977 48.8021 195.826 48.8021 195.725 48.8021L195.776 48.7512C194.014 48.4459 191.145 48.1914 189.887 48.8021ZM224.463 47.6317H225.016L224.966 51.3974C225.016 54.0436 224.613 56.8425 225.519 59.4378C226.627 61.8296 229.646 61.9822 231.911 61.9313C233.974 61.8804 236.692 61.3207 237.346 59.0307C238.152 55.4176 237.598 51.6518 237.799 47.937H238.353C238.403 50.9903 238.454 54.0436 238.353 57.046C238.303 58.9289 237.598 61.1171 235.736 61.8804C233.069 62.8473 230.049 62.8473 227.331 62.0331C225.217 61.4224 224.312 59.0816 224.312 57.046C224.312 53.8909 224.211 50.7359 224.463 47.6317ZM239.209 15.5719C236.742 16.9968 236.189 20.1518 236.139 22.7981C243.235 22.6454 250.381 22.7981 257.478 22.7472C257.226 20.4063 256.974 17.811 255.112 16.1825C252.948 14.5032 250.13 14.2488 247.513 14.147C244.694 14.147 241.725 14.2488 239.209 15.5719ZM236.843 13.1801C240.215 10.8393 244.543 10.8901 248.469 10.941C252.042 11.0937 256.068 11.8061 258.383 14.8594C260.749 18.0145 260.749 22.2383 260.799 26.0549C252.495 26.1058 244.191 26.004 235.937 26.1058C236.34 28.7011 236.541 31.958 239.209 33.2811C243.436 35.3675 248.519 35.164 252.998 34.0444C255.716 33.4338 257.327 30.7876 257.578 28.1413C258.736 28.1413 259.843 28.1413 261 28.1413C260.497 30.9911 259.541 33.9935 257.075 35.7237C253.451 38.2173 248.771 38.1664 244.543 38.0137C240.769 37.8102 236.441 36.6397 234.427 33.0775C232.565 29.668 232.565 25.6478 232.817 21.8821C233.119 18.6252 234.125 15.1648 236.843 13.1801ZM202.973 14.0452C205.388 11.9079 208.66 11.1955 211.78 10.9919C216.158 10.6357 220.94 11.1955 224.463 14.147C226.023 15.3683 226.828 17.2512 227.432 19.0832C226.325 19.0832 225.167 19.0832 224.06 19.0832C222.248 15.2157 217.618 14.0961 213.743 14.147C210.773 14.3506 207.401 14.5032 205.086 16.6914C203.627 17.9636 203.325 20.9152 205.338 21.8312C208.156 22.8998 211.277 22.3909 214.246 22.5436C218.121 22.6454 222.55 21.8821 225.922 24.3756C229.646 27.2762 228.589 33.79 224.513 35.8764C219.732 38.4717 213.944 38.4717 208.71 37.5048C204.633 36.8433 200.859 33.6882 200.305 29.4136C201.362 29.4136 202.469 29.4136 203.576 29.4136C204.08 30.9911 205.086 32.4669 206.596 33.2302C210.169 35.1131 214.397 35.1131 218.272 34.5533C220.386 34.1971 222.6 33.5864 224.06 31.9071C225.217 30.584 225.318 28.1413 223.859 27.0218C222.55 26.0549 220.839 25.9531 219.279 25.8005C215.454 25.6478 211.629 25.8005 207.804 25.6987C205.539 25.546 202.973 24.9354 201.614 22.8998C199.903 20.101 200.557 16.1825 202.973 14.0452ZM174.386 15.6737C171.971 17.0985 171.618 20.2027 171.316 22.7472C178.463 22.7981 185.609 22.7472 192.806 22.7472C192.504 20.6098 192.353 18.2181 190.793 16.5897C189.082 14.7577 186.415 14.4014 184.049 14.1979C180.778 14.0452 177.305 14.0961 174.386 15.6737ZM172.625 12.8239C176.198 10.6866 180.526 10.8393 184.502 10.941C187.925 11.1446 191.699 12.0097 193.813 15.0121C196.078 18.2181 196.078 22.2892 196.027 26.0549C187.774 26.0549 179.57 26.0549 171.316 26.0549C171.568 28.294 171.618 30.9911 173.531 32.5178C176.148 34.706 179.822 34.8077 183.043 34.8077C185.811 34.6042 188.881 34.4515 190.995 32.4669C192.253 31.3473 192.504 29.6171 192.857 28.0905C194.014 28.0905 195.121 28.0905 196.279 28.0905C195.776 30.9911 194.769 34.0953 192.202 35.7237C188.629 38.1155 184.15 38.0646 180.023 37.9628C176.45 37.7593 172.524 36.8942 170.259 33.8409C167.894 30.5331 167.995 26.2585 168.095 22.3909C168.297 18.8287 169.404 14.8086 172.625 12.8239ZM158.634 11.1955C159.691 11.1955 160.748 11.1955 161.804 11.1955C161.804 20.0501 161.804 28.9047 161.804 37.7593C160.748 37.7593 159.691 37.7593 158.684 37.7593C158.634 28.9047 158.634 20.0501 158.634 11.1955ZM108.004 11.1955C109.162 11.1955 110.319 11.1955 111.527 11.1955C114.194 18.4216 116.862 25.6478 119.529 32.874C119.73 33.2811 119.831 33.79 120.083 34.1462C120.586 34.8586 121.039 34.706 121.341 33.9426C123.757 27.2762 125.719 20.4063 128.135 13.7399C129.192 11.399 133.168 11.6535 133.822 14.1979L140.516 34.3498C140.616 34.6551 141.472 34.7569 141.623 34.2989C144.743 26.6656 147.36 18.8796 150.279 11.1955C151.437 11.1955 152.594 11.1955 153.802 11.1955C151.034 18.727 148.266 26.2585 145.448 33.7391C144.945 34.9604 144.441 36.3853 143.334 37.1486C141.975 37.9628 140.113 37.9628 138.754 37.0977C137.848 36.4362 137.446 35.2657 137.043 34.248C135.03 27.9887 132.916 21.7294 130.903 15.4701C128.89 21.5767 126.927 27.6834 124.914 33.79C124.511 34.9604 124.109 36.2326 123.102 37.0468C121.794 37.9628 119.932 38.0137 118.522 37.1995C117.365 36.4871 116.862 35.1131 116.358 33.8918C113.59 26.3603 110.772 18.7779 108.004 11.1955ZM159.54 2.23909C161.603 1.47576 163.465 4.27463 162.157 5.90306C160.999 7.63327 157.678 6.76817 157.879 4.52907C157.678 3.46041 158.583 2.54442 159.54 2.23909Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.66"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0_2_453">
<rect width="261" height="63" fill="white" transform="translate(0 -0.000488281)"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Пробовал использовать такой скрипт:

```
$('img.img-svg').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
    $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
      var $svg = $(data).find('svg');
      if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
        $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
      }
      $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
      if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
        $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
      }
      $img.replaceWith($svg);
    }, 'xml');
});
```

Но цвет всё равно не меняется через CSS

```
.blockname img.img-svg path{
    fill: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Js здесь явно лишний

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

svg g path{
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

svg:hover g path {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg
            width="261"
            height="63"
            viewBox="0 0 261 63"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_2_453)">
                <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M6.03942 -0.000488281H29.3412C27.3784 4.17237 28.083 9.10856 30.3478 12.9761C36.3871 23.6118 42.4768 34.2475 48.5664 44.8832C45.8487 49.5649 43.2317 54.2467 40.5643 58.9284C39.4068 60.9131 37.595 62.8977 35.1289 62.9486C32.6628 62.9995 30.7 61.1166 29.5425 59.0302C20.1815 42.7459 10.8709 26.3598 1.50992 10.0246C0.352378 7.98901 -0.553522 5.49547 0.453034 3.20549C1.40926 1.01728 3.87532 0.152177 6.03942 -0.000488281Z"
                    fill="white"
                    fill-opacity="0.66"
                />
                <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M38.35 -0.000488281H96.2773C98.3407 0.203066 100.656 0.864617 101.713 2.79838C102.87 4.98659 102.216 7.63279 101.058 9.66833C92.2007 25.1384 83.3933 40.6086 74.5357 56.1296C73.5291 57.8089 72.6735 59.6409 71.365 61.1166C70.0062 62.5924 67.8421 63.4575 65.8793 62.7451C64.0675 62.1344 62.7589 60.6077 61.8531 58.9793C52.4921 42.4914 43.0808 26.0544 33.6695 9.61744C32.5623 7.63279 31.8577 5.03748 33.0152 2.90016C34.0721 0.966394 36.2865 0.203066 38.35 -0.000488281Z"
                    fill="white"
                    fill-opacity="0.66"
                />
                <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M204.533 58.3691L205.388 58.42C205.791 59.4887 206.646 60.71 207.703 61.1171C210.371 62.1858 213.39 62.1349 216.108 61.3716C217.064 61.0662 218.121 60.5065 218.574 59.5905C218.826 59.1325 218.977 58.7254 219.027 58.2165C219.128 56.8934 218.121 55.7229 216.813 55.5194C213.34 54.9596 209.716 55.8756 206.344 54.8578C204.935 54.4507 204.382 52.7205 204.684 51.3974C204.935 49.9725 206.143 49.0056 207.401 48.4968C208.962 47.8861 210.673 47.7334 212.384 47.7843C213.944 47.8352 215.202 47.937 216.561 48.7512C217.668 49.4128 218.675 50.2779 219.128 51.601L218.272 51.8045C217.92 51.2956 217.165 50.4305 216.309 49.769C215.253 48.9548 214.548 48.8021 213.34 48.6494C211.075 48.2932 208.609 48.6494 206.697 49.8708C205.086 50.8376 204.885 53.8401 206.948 54.3998C210.522 55.3158 214.296 54.0436 217.819 55.214C218.876 55.5194 219.53 56.4863 219.782 57.504C220.084 58.878 219.53 60.1502 218.474 61.0662C216.259 62.9491 212.736 62.8982 209.867 62.542C207.452 62.1858 204.935 60.8627 204.533 58.3691ZM244.09 42.8481C244.292 42.8481 244.644 42.8481 244.845 42.8481C244.845 47.8861 244.845 53.8401 244.896 59.1834C244.896 60.4556 244.896 61.4733 245.097 62.7456L244.443 62.7964C243.939 61.4224 244.09 59.9467 244.09 58.5218C244.09 53.2803 244.04 48.0897 244.09 42.8481ZM251.237 42.8481C251.388 42.8481 251.69 42.8481 251.841 42.8481V47.9879L259.39 48.0388L259.34 48.6494H251.841C251.941 51.9572 251.64 55.3158 252.042 58.6236C252.193 59.9467 253.149 61.0153 254.408 61.3716C256.37 61.9822 258.484 61.6769 260.497 61.8296L260.598 62.2876C260.145 62.4402 258.987 62.3384 258.534 62.3893C256.572 62.3384 254.408 62.542 252.747 61.3207C251.489 60.3029 251.237 58.5727 251.187 57.046C251.187 54.2472 251.187 51.4483 251.187 48.5985C250.281 48.5985 249.375 48.5985 248.469 48.5985C248.469 48.4459 248.419 48.1405 248.419 47.9879C249.324 47.9879 250.281 47.9879 251.187 47.9879C251.237 46.2577 251.237 44.5783 251.237 42.8481ZM152.796 48.4968C151.89 48.4968 150.581 48.4459 148.92 49.6672C147.763 50.5323 147.159 52.059 147.058 53.4838C146.756 56.1809 146.907 59.8958 149.826 61.168C152.594 62.2367 155.815 62.1858 158.583 61.168C160.093 60.6082 160.697 59.0816 161.301 57.7076C161.452 57.6567 161.754 57.504 161.905 57.4531C161.704 59.6922 160.144 61.7787 157.879 62.1858C154.909 62.7964 151.638 62.9491 148.87 61.5242C145.951 59.6413 146.152 55.5703 146.555 52.4661C146.756 50.5832 148.115 49.1583 149.675 48.2932C150.33 47.937 150.783 47.8352 151.487 47.7843C153.249 47.6825 155.01 47.6825 156.772 47.7843C157.879 47.7843 158.382 48.1405 158.483 48.1914C160.244 49.0056 161.653 50.5832 161.905 52.5678C161.1 52.4152 160.898 51.4992 160.546 50.8885C160.244 50.227 159.741 49.7181 159.137 49.4128C158.382 48.9548 157.678 48.5985 156.822 48.4968C155.513 48.2932 154.004 48.5477 152.796 48.4968ZM170.612 48.4968C168.548 48.7003 166.737 50.2779 166.384 52.3643C165.881 55.1123 165.78 58.4709 167.844 60.6082C170.008 62.2367 172.927 61.9822 175.443 61.8296C177.456 61.7278 179.469 60.4556 179.922 58.42C180.577 55.7738 180.627 52.6696 179.167 50.2779C177.104 47.8352 173.48 48.2932 170.612 48.4968ZM169.203 48.1405C171.971 47.479 174.94 47.4281 177.658 48.2932C180.325 49.2092 181.08 52.4152 181.03 54.9596C181.08 57.5549 180.526 60.8627 177.809 61.9313C175.091 62.8982 172.071 62.7964 169.303 62.1858C166.334 61.5242 165.327 58.1656 165.378 55.4685C165.277 52.6696 166.082 49.0056 169.203 48.1405ZM189.887 48.8021C189.887 48.7512 189.887 48.7003 189.837 48.6494C188.327 48.9548 186.918 50.4305 186.717 51.9063C186.163 55.4176 186.616 59.0307 186.415 62.5929C185.559 62.2876 185.911 61.2698 185.811 60.6082C185.962 57.5549 185.509 54.4507 186.113 51.4483C186.314 49.8708 187.623 48.853 188.931 48.0897L190.139 47.8861C192.001 47.6825 193.863 47.6825 195.675 47.8352C195.776 47.8352 196.48 48.0388 196.833 48.0897L196.883 48.0388L196.984 48.0897C198.493 48.9548 199.701 50.3796 199.802 52.1607C200.054 55.5194 199.852 58.9289 199.903 62.3384C199.752 62.3384 199.45 62.3384 199.299 62.3384C199.198 58.9798 199.5 55.672 199.097 52.3134C198.946 50.7867 198.04 49.311 196.581 48.9039C196.43 48.853 196.279 48.853 196.078 48.8021C195.977 48.8021 195.826 48.8021 195.725 48.8021L195.776 48.7512C194.014 48.4459 191.145 48.1914 189.887 48.8021ZM224.463 47.6317H225.016L224.966 51.3974C225.016 54.0436 224.613 56.8425 225.519 59.4378C226.627 61.8296 229.646 61.9822 231.911 61.9313C233.974 61.8804 236.692 61.3207 237.346 59.0307C238.152 55.4176 237.598 51.6518 237.799 47.937H238.353C238.403 50.9903 238.454 54.0436 238.353 57.046C238.303 58.9289 237.598 61.1171 235.736 61.8804C233.069 62.8473 230.049 62.8473 227.331 62.0331C225.217 61.4224 224.312 59.0816 224.312 57.046C224.312 53.8909 224.211 50.7359 224.463 47.6317ZM239.209 15.5719C236.742 16.9968 236.189 20.1518 236.139 22.7981C243.235 22.6454 250.381 22.7981 257.478 22.7472C257.226 20.4063 256.974 17.811 255.112 16.1825C252.948 14.5032 250.13 14.2488 247.513 14.147C244.694 14.147 241.725 14.2488 239.209 15.5719ZM236.843 13.1801C240.215 10.8393 244.543 10.8901 248.469 10.941C252.042 11.0937 256.068 11.8061 258.383 14.8594C260.749 18.0145 260.749 22.2383 260.799 26.0549C252.495 26.1058 244.191 26.004 235.937 26.1058C236.34 28.7011 236.541 31.958 239.209 33.2811C243.436 35.3675 248.519 35.164 252.998 34.0444C255.716 33.4338 257.327 30.7876 257.578 28.1413C258.736 28.1413 259.843 28.1413 261 28.1413C260.497 30.9911 259.541 33.9935 257.075 35.7237C253.451 38.2173 248.771 38.1664 244.543 38.0137C240.769 37.8102 236.441 36.6397 234.427 33.0775C232.565 29.668 232.565 25.6478 232.817 21.8821C233.119 18.6252 234.125 15.1648 236.843 13.1801ZM202.973 14.0452C205.388 11.9079 208.66 11.1955 211.78 10.9919C216.158 10.6357 220.94 11.1955 224.463 14.147C226.023 15.3683 226.828 17.2512 227.432 19.0832C226.325 19.0832 225.167 19.0832 224.06 19.0832C222.248 15.2157 217.618 14.0961 213.743 14.147C210.773 14.3506 207.401 14.5032 205.086 16.6914C203.627 17.9636 203.325 20.9152 205.338 21.8312C208.156 22.8998 211.277 22.3909 214.246 22.5436C218.121 22.6454 222.55 21.8821 225.922 24.3756C229.646 27.2762 228.589 33.79 224.513 35.8764C219.732 38.4717 213.944 38.4717 208.71 37.5048C204.633 36.8433 200.859 33.6882 200.305 29.4136C201.362 29.4136 202.469 29.4136 203.576 29.4136C204.08 30.9911 205.086 32.4669 206.596 33.2302C210.169 35.1131 214.397 35.1131 218.272 34.5533C220.386 34.1971 222.6 33.5864 224.06 31.9071C225.217 30.584 225.318 28.1413 223.859 27.0218C222.55 26.0549 220.839 25.9531 219.279 25.8005C215.454 25.6478 211.629 25.8005 207.804 25.6987C205.539 25.546 202.973 24.9354 201.614 22.8998C199.903 20.101 200.557 16.1825 202.973 14.0452ZM174.386 15.6737C171.971 17.0985 171.618 20.2027 171.316 22.7472C178.463 22.7981 185.609 22.7472 192.806 22.7472C192.504 20.6098 192.353 18.2181 190.793 16.5897C189.082 14.7577 186.415 14.4014 184.049 14.1979C180.778 14.0452 177.305 14.0961 174.386 15.6737ZM172.625 12.8239C176.198 10.6866 180.526 10.8393 184.502 10.941C187.925 11.1446 191.699 12.0097 193.813 15.0121C196.078 18.2181 196.078 22.2892 196.027 26.0549C187.774 26.0549 179.57 26.0549 171.316 26.0549C171.568 28.294 171.618 30.9911 173.531 32.5178C176.148 34.706 179.822 34.8077 183.043 34.8077C185.811 34.6042 188.881 34.4515 190.995 32.4669C192.253 31.3473 192.504 29.6171 192.857 28.0905C194.014 28.0905 195.121 28.0905 196.279 28.0905C195.776 30.9911 194.769 34.0953 192.202 35.7237C188.629 38.1155 184.15 38.0646 180.023 37.9628C176.45 37.7593 172.524 36.8942 170.259 33.8409C167.894 30.5331 167.995 26.2585 168.095 22.3909C168.297 18.8287 169.404 14.8086 172.625 12.8239ZM158.634 11.1955C159.691 11.1955 160.748 11.1955 161.804 11.1955C161.804 20.0501 161.804 28.9047 161.804 37.7593C160.748 37.7593 159.691 37.7593 158.684 37.7593C158.634 28.9047 158.634 20.0501 158.634 11.1955ZM108.004 11.1955C109.162 11.1955 110.319 11.1955 111.527 11.1955C114.194 18.4216 116.862 25.6478 119.529 32.874C119.73 33.2811 119.831 33.79 120.083 34.1462C120.586 34.8586 121.039 34.706 121.341 33.9426C123.757 27.2762 125.719 20.4063 128.135 13.7399C129.192 11.399 133.168 11.6535 133.822 14.1979L140.516 34.3498C140.616 34.6551 141.472 34.7569 141.623 34.2989C144.743 26.6656 147.36 18.8796 150.279 11.1955C151.437 11.1955 152.594 11.1955 153.802 11.1955C151.034 18.727 148.266 26.2585 145.448 33.7391C144.945 34.9604 144.441 36.3853 143.334 37.1486C141.975 37.9628 140.113 37.9628 138.754 37.0977C137.848 36.4362 137.446 35.2657 137.043 34.248C135.03 27.9887 132.916 21.7294 130.903 15.4701C128.89 21.5767 126.927 27.6834 124.914 33.79C124.511 34.9604 124.109 36.2326 123.102 37.0468C121.794 37.9628 119.932 38.0137 118.522 37.1995C117.365 36.4871 116.862 35.1131 116.358 33.8918C113.59 26.3603 110.772 18.7779 108.004 11.1955ZM159.54 2.23909C161.603 1.47576 163.465 4.27463 162.157 5.90306C160.999 7.63327 157.678 6.76817 157.879 4.52907C157.678 3.46041 158.583 2.54442 159.54 2.23909Z"
                    fill="white"
                    fill-opacity="0.66"
                />
            </g>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0_2_453">
                    <rect
                        width="261"
                        height="63"
                        fill="white"
                        transform="translate(0 -0.000488281)"
                    />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Добавлено в CSS вместо svg { transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; } => svg g path {transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;} так как `transition` не работал.

Comment: Да, ошибочка=)_